# Netbeans PHPUnit Tests were not generated

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

When trying to create a test for a file with a class, I get the following error:

```
Tests were not generated for the following files:

myclass.php

Review the log in Output windows
```

When looking at Output:

```
Restricted access
```

The test class file is not created but the directory tree is.

I have noticed this happens with classes that extend another class. With classes with no extend, the test file is correctly created.

Comment: Are the classes they extend on the include path?

Comment: I have now included the main folders but the tests generation are still not working. Do you know if adding a folder to the include path will include subfolders and files recursively?

Comment: It will include subfolders, but only if the `require` has the full subpath. Meaning if you have a file at `/foo/bar/baz/php` and you add `/foo` to the include path, `require 'bar/baz.php'` will work but not `require 'baz.php'`.

Comment: Where are you adding this to the include path? You must make PHPUnit aware of these paths so much do it in `bootstrap.php` or `phpunit.xml` I believe (or `php.ini` of course but that's not a good idea).

Comment: The bootstrap.php has all the includes necessary to run. The problem is when I use Netbeans "Create PHPUnit tests" feaure that can be found when right-clicking at a file and going to Tools>Create PHPUnit tests.

Comment: NetBeans uses PHPUnit to generate the file, and I believe that PHPUnit will run `bootstrap.php` first. Have you set the bootstrap file for the project in NetBeans? Can you run unit tests for this project inside NetBeans?

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is there. Yes, actually I can run other tests within netbeans.

Comment: To verify that your `bootstrap.php` is being used when generating tests, add some code that will fail to it. You might want to try PHPUnit's IRC channel or user mailing list so Sebastian Bergmann will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Check if File / Project Properties/ Test Folder is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing something inside Joomla? It seems the "restricted access" that Joomla says when the _JEXEC is not defined.
Try to put this on top of your bootstrap file

```
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
```